# Unable to run docker within the container. Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run docker inside a container with my app that creates images and build them. I've read that if I bind docker.sock from my host computer (In the docker-compose.yml) I can do it, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error, Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

My code:

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  lqcli-backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: lqcli-backend
    container_name: lqcli-backend
    volumes:
      # Bind Docker socket on the host so we can connect to the daemon from
      # within the container
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

# Download all the dependencies
RUN go get -d -v ./...

# Install the package
RUN go install -v ./...

RUN go install lqcli.go
RUN go build lqcli.go

RUN mkdir /var/local/lightquery
WORKDIR /var/local/lightquery
RUN cp /go/src/app/lqcliconfig.yml .
RUN cp -R /go/src/app/templatefolder/ .
RUN cp -R /go/src/app/buildfolder/ .
RUN chown -R $(whoami) /var/local/lightquery/

WORKDIR /go/src/app

RUN lqcli -d example2.py -task example2

CMD ["lqcli","-d","example2.py"]
```

I have also try to RUN service docker start but It doesn't work:

```
------
 > [15/16] RUN service docker start:
#19 0.410 docker: unrecognized service
------
```

**Edit:**
Complete error message:

```
loren@RONDAN1:/mnt/c/Users/rondan/Desktop/lightquery-cli$ docker-compose up --build
Building lqcli-backend
[+] Building 27.6s (19/19) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:latest                                                   2.3s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.3s
 => => transferring context: 4.23kB                                                                                0.3s
 => [ 1/15] FROM docker.io/library/golang:latest@sha256:7f69ee6e3ea6c3acab98576d8d51bf2e72ed722a0bd4e4363423fddb3  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/15] WORKDIR /go/src/app                                                                             0.0s
 => [ 3/15] COPY . .                                                                                               0.0s
 => [ 4/15] RUN go get -d -v ./...                                                                                 9.7s
 => [ 5/15] RUN go install -v ./...                                                                                8.7s
 => [ 6/15] RUN go install lqcli.go                                                                                1.6s
 => [ 7/15] RUN go build lqcli.go                                                                                  1.5s
 => [ 8/15] RUN mkdir /var/local/lightquery                                                                        0.5s
 => [ 9/15] WORKDIR /var/local/lightquery                                                                          0.1s
 => [10/15] RUN cp /go/src/app/lqcliconfig.yml .                                                                   0.4s
 => [11/15] RUN cp -R /go/src/app/templatefolder/ .                                                                0.6s
 => [12/15] RUN cp -R /go/src/app/buildfolder/ .                                                                   0.5s
 => [13/15] RUN chown -R $(whoami) /var/local/lightquery/                                                          0.6s
 => [14/15] WORKDIR /go/src/app                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [15/15] RUN lqcli -d example2.py -task example2                                                          0.8s
------
 > [15/15] RUN lqcli -d example2.py -task example2:
[████████████                                      ] 25%       25/100Error, Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
#19 0.762 [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x49ea13]
#19 0.762
#19 0.762 goroutine 1 [running]:
#19 0.762 io.ReadAll(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1)
#19 0.762       /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:633 +0xb3
#19 0.762 io/ioutil.ReadAll(...)
#19 0.762       /usr/local/go/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go:27
#19 0.762 main.buildDocker(0xc000105d70, 0x22, 0xc000105da0, 0x25, 0xc00033ff10)
#19 0.762       /go/src/app/lqcli.go:328 +0x83d
#19 0.762 main.main()
#19 0.762       /go/src/app/lqcli.go:571 +0x350
```

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: I'm trying on Windows with WSL(Ubuntu terminal) and Ubuntu with the same result @gust

Answer (score 1):

Is the error happening INSIDE the running container (not during docker build)? I will assume so, but if not, you cannot access the docker daemon from inside a build.

You need the following things for this kind of setup to work-

1. You need a docker CLIENT inside your image. `apt install docker-cli` or the like
2. You need a docker DAEMON exposed to your container. Bind mounting like you did there works so long as the daemon is setup to listen that way
3. You need PERMISSION for the daemon, inside your container. By default the daemon is using a unix socket, so the user running in your container must have unix filesystem permissions to write to that socket

You didn't post an error message, so can't guess which was your issue.

Comment: The error is happening inside the running container, I edited the post adding the full error message.

Comment: no, it is happening in `docker-compose build` which means it is in the build phase. I don't believe there is any way to make that work, and even if there was, its the wrong way to do it (the build images would be useless inside the image)